Nestjs with fastify adapter broken on v10
I updated nestjs to the v10, and tried to implement fastify adapter but it throws 200+ types errors inside the node_modules/fastify/types
Versions:
"@nestjs/common": "^10.3.10",
"@nestjs/core": "^10.3.10",
"@nestjs/platform-fastify": "^10.3.10",
Also, typescript version is 5.5.3.
Issue when running yarn start:dev :
node_modules/fastify/types/instance.d.ts:205:5 - error TS1139: Type parameter declaration expected.

205     const SchemaCompiler extends FastifySchema = FastifySchema,
        ~~~~~

node_modules/fastify/types/instance.d.ts:205:26 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

205     const SchemaCompiler extends FastifySchema = FastifySchema,
                             ~~~~~~~

node_modules/fastify/types/instance.d.ts:206:3 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

206   >(opts: RouteOptions<RawServer, RawRequest, RawReply, RouteGeneric, ContextConfig, SchemaCompiler, TypeProvider, Logger>): FastifyInstance<RawServer, RawRequest, RawReply, Logger, TypeProvider>;
      ~

node_modules/fastify/types/instance.d.ts:206:9 - error TS1005: ')' expected.

206   >(opts: RouteOptions<RawServer, RawRequest, RawReply, RouteGeneric, ContextConfig, SchemaCompiler, TypeProvider, Logger>): FastifyInstance<RawServer, RawRequest, RawReply, Logger, TypeProvider>;
            ~

Upgraded all dependencies, typescript.

can you run  npm ls fastify? share the output in the question
